# Tapping into the Org's limits

Tags: limits

How can I tap into my org's limits/usage programmatically?
I know of the Limits class but that seems to only show me usage for the current execution 'thread' I would like to tap into the org wide usage and monitor it via APEX code (without going to some SF page).

Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't currently possible to programmatically introspect all org wide limits.

However here are some previous responses particularly around future method counts

http://www.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3380/how-can-i-determine-how-many-future-calls-have-been-executed-in-24-hours

http://www.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5376/how-can-you-avoid-hitting-24-hour-limits-on-emails-and-future-calls

There is always screen scraping if you're really desperate
http://www.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3916/getting-remaining-licenses-of-customer-portal-using-apex