# How do I troubleshoot @future jobs that simply vanishes?

Tags: future, debug

I am working in an environment where some @future jobs seems to vanish. It's a quite complex org so I'll try to explain as clearly and detailed as possible.

When a lead changes Status a new record should be created through a future job.

My code iterates through the trigger.new and trigger.old lists and detects any changes for the status. If there is a change the lead Id will be stored in a list and handed over to the future method/job. Sometimes the job/method is called but never get's executed - and I can't find it in the Apex Job-list. The transaction that calls the future method completes successfully (I have debug traces that shows this).

Here's some an excerpt from the log:

> 11:57:40.572 (1604908711)|LIMIT_USAGE|[161]|FUTURE|1|50

Shows that future method on line 161 has been scheduled.

I can also see that the cumulative limits counts up:

Number of future calls: 1 out of 50

There are workflows and process builders in this org that updates the record causing the triggers to execute twice. When this happens the cumulative limits are cleared in the log (it happens for all the limits). Is this normal?

Any ideas how a scheduled future job can just vanish without the transaction failing? How can this be troubleshoot forward?

Any ideas would be most appreciated!

Comment: does a record get created? If you're the one that's starting the transaction and you leave dev console open (or put debug logs on yourself), you should see logs related to it if it runs. It might help to put in the code (just the relevant parts)

Comment: No, the record is not created (the future job never runs). I have debug logs - they indicate the future method has been called / scheduled. But it never executes. The transaction doesn't error/exception/fail. Nothing in the Apex Jobs log either.

Comment: [Take a look](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3380/how-can-i-determine-how-many-future-calls-have-been-executed-in-24-hours) at `AsyncApexJob` - if your future call is in there, its status will tell you what's up. If not in there, then it didn't get queued.

Comment: There is nothing in the AsyncApexJob for the missing calls. But if it wasn't scheduled why isn't there an error in the debug logs?

Comment: Does the transaction fail or do you have a database.rollback() that covers the future job call?

Comment: I'm not using savepoints or rollbacks here. And I cant see anything like that in the logs either. There are no exceptions at all and no other indication on that the transaction is failing.

Comment: There's a small possibility you found a bug in SF platform. A more likely root cause is that the transaction is rolled back, that can happen without a savepoint. Open a case with SF support.

Comment: Thanks - yes, I have a support case running. Lets see what they come back with. This is quite strange to me.

Comment: What if you temporarily omit the future annotation? Does it work all the time?

Comment: @Muxlix were you able to get any inputs from salesforce on this?